# Interceptor behaviour for mobile first platform

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

is there any mechanism to use a intercepting behavior in MFP 8 server side components  for all requests where we can add some business logic check , or like a validator at first level for an adapter call.

So based on the comments i created a jaxrs interceptor example which works fine in a normal java ee context  but not in the mfp . below example 
Example Interceptor

```
@Interceptor 
public class LoggerInterceptor  {

@AroundInvoke
public Object loggerMethod(InvocationContext context) throws Exception{

    String className = context.getMethod().getDeclaringClass().getName();
    String methodName = context.getMethod().getName();
    System.out.println(String.format("[Logger]ENTRY POINT: %s.%s", className, methodName));
    return context.proceed();
} }
```

Also the mapping on the adapter resource

```
@GET
@Path("/getDetails")
@OAuthSecurity(enabled = false)
@Interceptors(LoggerInterceptor.class)
public JSONObject getDetails(@Context HttpServletRequest request,  @Context HttpServletResponse response)
```

Comment: Please clarify your request with an actual example of your intent.

Comment: We tried to you the Jax-rs interceptor , Created a class which would act as the interceptor  - but may be its not getting initialized for the mfp container

Answer (score 1):

MFP8 has full support for JAX-RS 2.0 features, therefore you can use JAX-RS filters and interceptors (such as [ContainerRequestFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html) for example)  in an adapter. This can be used to implement validation logic before the actual adapter code is executed.

Note however that that since adapters are individually sandboxed there is no way to implement such logic for many adapters without adding it to every adapter.

Comment: How do we do so with MFP 7.1.0, as it comes with JAX-RS 1.x?

Answer (score 1):

ofcourse, as with all JAX RS standard interceptors, you can also write post-adapter validation...(i.e: modify the response)